# Backstage Heroku Deployment

Tags: heroku, backend, backstage

WHy am I keep getting this error.

> Backend failed to start up, Error: Failed to connect to the database to make sure that 'backstage_plugin_catalog' exists, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your postgres-database with the environment variable POSTGRES_DB=backstage_plugin_catalog.
Also, check the credentials for postgres.

Comment: Hi @Lukas, the docker image still has issues. Did try to connect the DB parameters from Heroku-Postgres, does that affect the docker run by any chance. ?? Any thghts ?

Comment: Hi Lukas, the app deployment in Heroku still has issues. Actually as of now just trying to create an app and deploy it, the contents and stuffs are planned for later.

Comment: I had created the Backstage app, it runs fine with the postgreSQL DB locally. But while deploying throws an error of "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.92.207.6", user "aasenmiqcxbzed", database "postgres", no encryption"

Comment: Ah I see, so it runs locally but not in Heroku. I am sorry but I am not famillar with Heroku.
But maybe this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host